# Mistake in my pdo if statement

Tags: php, pdo

I want to add to database user_id and fav_id. But only if they both together are not recorded yet.
I did something wrong in my code becayse it all the time adds it.
Why does that happen?

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';

$fav_id = $_POST['fav_id'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

$number = $pdo-> query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favourites WHERE user_id = :user_id AND fav_id = fav_id ');

if ($number == 0) {
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO `favourites` (`fav_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (" . $fav_id . "," . $user_id . ")");
}
else die();

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried var_dump on $number?

Comment: query returns PDOStatement object, not a number

Comment: Your `count` statement is strange. Where are you assigning `:user_id` and `fav_id`? Also, why does one have the `:` and the other not?

Comment: @JAL it shows "bool(false)"

Comment: Oh, that means the query failed. You're not seeing any errors? Try adding $pdo->setAttribute("PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE", PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `fetchColumn()`

more over i think you should be preparing the statement with :user-id and fav_id

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';

$fav_id = $_POST['fav_id'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

$number = $pdo-> prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favourites WHERE user_id = :user_id AND fav_id = :fav_id ');

$number ->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id,':fav_id'=>$fav_id));

if ($number ->fetchColumn() == 0) {
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO `favourites` (`fav_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (" . $fav_id . "," . $user_id . ")");
}
else die();

?>
```

Comment: oh, come on, [fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) can return FALSE here

Comment: Why do you have two semicolons? `'fav_id'=>$fav_id));;`

Comment: Doesn't the `execute()` array have colons? `array(':user_id' => $user_id,':fav_id'=>$fav_id)`

Comment: This works great! thank you :) I have to work more on PDO its hard to understand for me comparing to easy mysql

Comment: @Rasclatt arent they optional? why they work for me without it? just for knowledge

Comment: I think the colons are used when you assign actual `key` values, and no colons when you assign `?` in the statement. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php   But I could be wrong...that's not uncommon for me!!

Comment: @Rasclatt yes manual says that but i have got it working before wwithout colons thats strange or may be by luck

Comment: @A.B because this function [returns FALSE](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) on empty `SELECT` result, you should try [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) if you want an int number

Comment: @vladkras if you look at the PDO manual regarding `SELECT` and `rowCount()`, it is recommended not to use it with `SELECT` statements: "If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."

Comment: @Rasclatt yes, but you can easily check this. Do you think relying on `false == 0` is better? While `false !== 0`. Look at [this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2b4r-sgf7) rowCount() definitely returns `int(0)` and fetchColumn() returns `bool(false)`

Comment: @vladkras I am just just passing on a cautionary note regarding using `rowCount()` on a `SELECT`

Comment: @Rasclatt I see your point, but note about [fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) also says: _or FALSE if there are no more rows_. `FALSE` not `0` It can never be `int(0)`, only `string` or `FALSE`, so this is a bad bad coding style